# MongoDB collection is not recognized on client side

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am playing Meteor and found it did not work as expected. I am supposed to see the collection on both server side and client side. However, it seems I cannot see the collection on client side.

In the following example, when I typed "Products.find({})" in Chrome console, I encountered:

> VM1592:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Products is not defined

client/main.html:

```
<body>
  {{> addProduct}}
</body>

<template name="addProduct">

  <form class="addNewProduct">
    product name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

client/main.js:

```
import {Products} from "/lib/collections/products";
import './main.html';
Template.addProduct.events({

  'submit .addNewProduct'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name.value;

    Products.insert({ name });
  },
});
```

lib/collection/products.js:

```
export const Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
```

I did not remove "autopublish".
What is really wrong here?

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using Meteor 1.3 or later, so it makes sense because in these versions Meteor adapts ES6 module system. Therefore your collection can not be accessed globally. If you want to access them in client console, I suggest this code in `client/main.js`:

```
import { Products } from "/lib/collections/products";
import './main.html';

if (Meteor.isDevelopment) {
  window.Products = Products;
}

Template.addProduct.events({
  // ...
});
```

This will let you access the `Products` collection in client console when developing but not on production.

Comment: So Meteor 1.3+ will not support direct access to collections any more?

Comment: Not really, if you define a variable outside out `imports` folder without a `var/let/const`, that variable could be accessed globally.

Comment: In other words, if you are using var/let/const or your files are under folder "imports", your collection will not be accessible by client side. Is this correct>